# When selecting from the Menu not able to Perform task?

Tags: bash, shell-script, menu

Is there a way to automatically create users, delete users, create groups and delete groups once I selected a task? Also Why im not able to perform any of those task once I select the task I want to perform but instead I'm getting prompt to enter your selection when I choose a task?

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
 clear
 echo "========================="
 echo "Menu ---"
 echo "========================="
 echo "Enter 1 to Create Group 1: "
 echo "Enter 2 to Remove Group 2: "
 echo "Enter 3 to Create User  3: "
 echo "Enter 4 to Remove User  4: "
 echo "Enter q to exit the menu q: "
 echo -e "\n"
 echo -e "Enter Your selection \c"
 read answer
 case "$answer" in
 1) groupadd ;;
 2) groupdel ;;
 3) useradd ;;
 4) userdel ;;
 q) exit ;;
 esac
 echo -e  "Enter return to continue \c"
 read input
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the Name of your User or Group:

```
useradd Krup

groupadd KrupGroup
```

and the same for delete

so your script will be something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
clear
echo "========================="
echo "Menu ---"
echo "========================="
echo "Enter 1 to Create Group 1: "
echo "Enter 2 to Remove Group 2: "
echo "Enter 3 to Create User  3: "
echo "Enter 4 to Remove User  4: "
echo "Enter q to exit the menu q: "
echo -e "\n"
echo -e "Enter Your selection \c"
read answer
case "$answer" in
1) echo "enter Group name to add"; read group ;groupadd $group ;;
2) echo "enter Group name to delete"; read group ;groupdel $group ;;
3) echo "enter User name to add"; read user ;useradd $user ;;
4) echo "enter User name to delete"; read user ; userdel $user ;;
q) exit ;;
esac
echo -e  "Enter return to continue \c"
read input
done
```

Comment: welcome to this site, I hope you read the about page: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour, to accept an answer you just click on the tick beside the answer.

Comment: I'd rather use `select` here - this all looks a bit clumsy to me (let alone hard to expand for future additions). But heck, it was accepted as best solution, so I'm not going to mess with it any more.